# SimpleXLSX errors trying to parse file

Tags: php

I'm trying to use SimpleXLSX to read a one sheet xls file and display some of the data on a web page in the same way I had previously done with ASP, however when testing the code there seems to be a problem parsing the xls data to create the XML file in order for the next stage of the process to complete (reading and displaying the data).

I have tried to simplify the spreadsheet to remove any issues of complexity that may have been causing the error, but still not joy.

The initial error I was getting with the full spreadsheet was:-

XML-entry theme/theme/themeManager.xml parser error line ?>

And the new error with the supposedly simplified spreadsheet is:-

Unknown archive format ?>

Any suggestions as to what might be causing these errors?

Thanks in advance,

Rob

Comment: Could you share the piece of code you tried and failed

Comment: <?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/simplexlsx.class.php';
if ( $xlsx = SimpleXLSX::parse('bookings2.xls')) {
 echo '<h1>$xlsx->rows()</h1>';
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r( $xlsx->rows() );
 echo '</pre>';

 echo '<h1>$xlsx->rowsEx()</h1>';
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r( $xlsx->rowsEx() );
 echo '</pre>';
} else {
 echo SimpleXLSX::parse_error();
}
?>

Comment: I've just tried copying a small section of the data into an xlsx file using the online excel program and it seems to read that fine, but I would like to use my current spreadsheet (xls format) as it has loads of macros on it to calculate various elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try saving it in XLSX format instead of XLS. That works for me.

If you don't have a way to do that, you can try [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download/) or [OpenOffice](https://www.openoffice.org/product/index.html). I haven't used OpenOffice in several years, but I imagine it'll do it.